# Error when evaluating the primality of an integer by dividing it by all integers in range(1,100) and checking if the result yields a whole number

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a python game that finds whether an integer is prime or not by dividing it by all integers in range(1,100) and checking if the result yields a whole number. Is my approach correct, or is there a better way to do this?

This is the code I have written so far. Right now I am getting an error on line 3. Also, feedback on the efficiency of my method would be appreciated.

```
z = int(input("Please give me a number"))
x = range(1, 1000)
for i in x if int(z /= i) in range(0, 1000) :
  print("non prime")
else:
  print("prime")
```

Comment: Think about what happens if the number you enter isn't prime, but its smallest divisor is larger than 999.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error - you can't use an if in a for loop.

Overall the better way to do this is to use the modulus operator.

```py
for i in range(2, z/2):
  if z % i == 0:
      print("non prime")
      break
else:
  print("prime")
```

In this code I'm making it more efficient by going up until half of z - the largest possible factor of a number is half of itself. It also breaks when it finds the first factor as there is no need to keep testing.

I also changed the range to start at 2 since you can't divide by 0 and 1 is a factor of everything.

For else is an unusual patten where the else only activates when the for isn't broken.

Comment: You can further limit the range to not just `z/2` but `sqrt(z)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a statement like the one below, which checks every item in the range `x` and if it divides, adds it to a list. It then checks the length of the list, if this is 2 or less then the number is prime, else it is not prime:

```
z = int(input("Please give me a number"))
x = range(1, 1000)

print("prime" if len([i for i in x if z%i==0]) == 2 else "non prime")
```